# How to read a database view in rapidminer

Tags: database, view, rapidminer

Does anyone know how to read a view from a database into rapidminer?  I have a connection set up to a Microsoft SQL server, and I'm using the Read Database operator, but it only shows a list of tables, not views.  The has been set up, and I can see it using Access.  The view is being worked on while I'm working in rapidminer so I need a live link to it, rather than re-creating the query in rapidminer.  Is there something I'm missing, or does rapidminer just not support views?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the Read Database operator you can type in table names manually, even if they are not part of the drop down list - so just type `myViewName` into the drop down list. Alternatively, you can select `query` for the define_query parameter, and enter something like `SELECT * FROM myViewName` into the dialog accessible via Build SQL Query.

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't seem to work - just gave a SQLError that the name doesn't exist.  However, checking is Access proves that it does exist...

Comment: Ok, Nevermind.  Just had another, closer, look in Access and discovered that the DB administrator spelled the view name wrong.  Duh!